# How to change the number of columns in an array (console.log)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I have a function that returns an array of values.
When I use `console.log(myFunction(arguments))`, the following array is returned:

```js
[
  'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1',
  'G1', 'H1', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2',
  'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'B3',
  'C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'F3', 'G3',
  'H3', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4',
  'F4', 'G4', 'H4', 'B5', 'C5',
  'D5', 'E5', 'F5', 'G5', 'H5'
]
```

There are 5 columns. I want to display an array of 7 columns. How can I do it?

Comment: Which console are you looking at? Mine doesn't format arrays with columns at all.

Comment: @Bergi Powershell (embedded in VS code)

Comment: You mean with node.js?

Comment: @Bergi yep, I mean with node.js

Comment: Call `util.inspect` directly and pass the [`breakLength` option](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options)

Comment: @Bergi can you give an example please?

Comment: See the answers on the duplicate targets